# Select a value in drop down using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to select a value from drop down of a service now form. I am able to retrieve the values in the dropdown. But i am not able to select a value. Here is my code..

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.FullScreen = true
IE.Navigate URL  

WScript.Sleep 15000

Set obj = ie.document.getElementById("sp_formfield_IO:7bb004650f30da00471ce498b1050e97")
For Each opt In obj.Options
If opt.Value = "Data Request" then
    opt.Selected = True
    obj.FireEvent ("onchange")
    Exit For
Else
    opt.Selected = False
End If
Next
```

Here is my HTML code for the Dropbox section

```
<select name="IO:7bb004650f30da00471ce498b1050e97" tabindex="-1" title="{{field.label}}{{::field.hint}}" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-isolate-scope select2-offscreen ng-not-empty" id="sp_formfield_IO:7bb004650f30da00471ce498b1050e97" aria-invalid="false" ng-init="setPriceLabelForChoice(field)" options="field.choices" ng-model="fieldValue" ng-disabled="field.isReadonly()" ng-switch-when="choice" glide-form="getGlideForm()" field="field" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}" sn-select-width="auto" ng-options="c.value as getLabel(c) for c in field.choices track by getVal(c.value)"><option value=" " label="Please Select">Please Select</option><option value="Data Request" label="Data Request">Data Request</option><option value="Initial Build" label="Initial Build">Initial Build</option><option value="Defect Fix" label="Defect Fix">Defect Fix</option><option value="Schema Changes" label="Schema Changes">Schema Changes</option><option value="Other" label="Other">Other</option></select>
```

How do i fix this to select a value from the dropdown?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing the `opt.Value` with the `opt.Text`?

Comment: opt.Value in the if condition is working fine. I checked by putting a msgbox inside if condition. But once inside the if condition check, opt.selected=true is not setting the value of dropdown to "Data Request"..